# How do I create a dijit TextBox programmatically?

Tags: dojo, dijit.form

So, I have a DialogBox in which I am asking for a new text as input. Basically it is a Dialog for renaming an element and I need the new value for the name. But I am unable to figure out how to create the textbox programmatically. Doing declaratively is not an option.

Comment: check the links which might help. links [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613813/how-to-programatically-add-and-use-elements-dialog-box-in-this-case) , [two](http://www.sohua.xyz/questions/1254545/how-to-make-and-display-a-form-in-a-dijit-dialog-programmatically) and [three](http://www.ideacode.com/content/the-definitive-guide-to-powerhouse-dojo-dialog-forms)

Comment: Thank you! The second link worked for me! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following answer is taken from link [two](http://www.sohua.xyz/questions/1254545/how-to-make-and-display-a-form-in-a-dijit-dialog-programmatically)

```
require([
    "dijit/Dialog", 
    "dijit/form/Form", 
    "dijit/form/TextBox", 
    "dijit/form/Button", 
    "dojo/domReady!" 
], function(Dialog, Form, TextBox, Button) 
{
    var form = new Form();

    new TextBox({
        placeHolder: "Name"
    }).placeAt(form.containerNode);

    new Button({
      label: "OK"
    }).placeAt(form.containerNode);

    var dia = new Dialog({
        content: form,
        title: "Dialog with form",
        style: "width: 300px; height: 300px;"
    });
    form.startup();
    dia.show();
});//~require
```